# How solve this issue : java.lang.NumberFormatException in android?

Tags: android, bar-chart, numberformatexception

I am creating a bar-chart in android,but i am getting the these errors on my logcat,what does this means?Suggestion please...

Can anyone please let me know the solution?

**Logcat**

```
10-03 12:39:26.965: W/KeyCharacterMap(524): No keyboard for id 0
10-03 12:39:26.965: W/KeyCharacterMap(524): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
10-03 12:39:45.455: D/AndroidRuntime(524): Shutting down VM
10-03 12:39:45.455: W/dalvikvm(524): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
10-03 12:39:45.475: E/AndroidRuntime(524): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-03 12:39:45.475: E/AndroidRuntime(524): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test_wb/com.example.test_wb.ResultActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: 
10-03 12:39:45.475: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
10-03 12:39:45.475: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
10-03 12:39:45.475: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
10-03 12:39:45.475: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
10-03 12:39:45.475: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-03 12:39:45.475: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-03 12:39:45.475: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
10-03 12:39:45.475: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-03 12:39:45.475: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-03 12:39:45.475: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
10-03 12:39:45.475: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
10-03 12:39:45.475: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-03 12:39:45.475: E/AndroidRuntime(524): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: 
10-03 12:39:45.475: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.util.FloatingPointParser.parseDblImpl(Native Method)
10-03 12:39:45.475: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.util.FloatingPointParser.parseDouble(FloatingPointParser.java:283)
10-03 12:39:45.475: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:287)
10-03 12:39:45.475: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at com.example.test_wb.ResultActivity.onCreate(ResultActivity.java:40)
10-03 12:39:45.475: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
10-03 12:39:45.475: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
10-03 12:39:45.475: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  ... 11 more
```

**ResultActivity.java**

```
public class ResultActivity extends Activity 
{   
TextView txt1,txt2;

String a,b;
double x_axis,y_axis;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{   
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main1);

Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

if(extras != null)
{   
    a = extras.getString("gotonextpageX");
    b = extras.getString("gotonextpageY");

    double x_axis = Double.parseDouble(a); // Type casting
    double y_axis = Double.parseDouble(b); // Type casting

  }
else
{

}

draw();

//txt1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtVw);
//txt2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtVw2);
//txt1.setText(x);
//txt2.setText(y);
}

public void draw()
{   

String[] titles = new String[] { "Order's profit of the year", " " };

List<double[]> values = new ArrayList<double[]>();

values.add(new double[] { y_axis });

int[] colors = new int[] { Color.BLACK, Color.WHITE};

XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = buildBarRenderer(colors);
renderer.setOrientation(Orientation.HORIZONTAL);

 setChartSettings(renderer, "Profit for the year 2012", " ", " ",0,x_axis, 0,y_axis, Color.GRAY, Color.LTGRAY);

renderer.setXLabels(1);
renderer.addXTextLabel(100, "x");

//renderer.addXTextLabel(200, "ord2");
//renderer.addXTextLabel(300, "ord3");
//renderer.addXTextLabel(400, "ord4");
//renderer.setPanEnabled(true, false);

int length = renderer.getSeriesRendererCount();

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
{
    SimpleSeriesRenderer seriesRenderer = renderer.getSeriesRendererAt(i);
    seriesRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
    }

ChartFactory.getBarChartIntent(this, buildBarDataset(titles, values), renderer,Type.DEFAULT);
}

protected XYMultipleSeriesRenderer buildBarRenderer(int[] colors) 
{   

  // creates a SeriesRenderer and initializes it with useful default values as well as colors

    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();

    renderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(15);
    renderer.setChartTitleTextSize(20);
    renderer.setLabelsTextSize(15);
    renderer.setLegendTextSize(15);

    int length = colors.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
    {
        SimpleSeriesRenderer r = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
        r.setColor(colors[i]);
        renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);
        }
    return renderer;
    }

protected void setChartSettings(XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer, String title, String xTitle,
String yTitle, double xMin, double x_axis2, double yMin, double yMax, int axesColor,int labelsColor) 
{   

// sets lots of default values for this renderer

renderer.setChartTitle(title);
renderer.setXTitle(xTitle);
renderer.setYTitle(yTitle);

renderer.setXAxisMin(xMin);

//renderer.setXAxisMax(x2);

renderer.setYAxisMin(yMin);
renderer.setYAxisMax(yMax);

renderer.setAxesColor(axesColor);
renderer.setLabelsColor(labelsColor);

renderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
renderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
}

protected XYMultipleSeriesDataset buildBarDataset(String[] titles, List<double[]> values) 
{   
// adds the axis titles and values into the data-set

XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
int length = titles.length;

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
{
    CategorySeries series = new CategorySeries(titles[i]);

    double[] v = values.get(i);
    int seriesLength = v.length;

    for (int k = 0; k < seriesLength; k++) 
    {
        series.add(v[k]);
    }

    dataset.addSeries(series.toXYSeries());
}
return dataset;
}}
```

**Main_WB.java**

```
public class Main_WB extends Activity
{
EditText edt1, edt2;
// TextView txt_1;

Button btn;
ArrayList<String> result;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

edt1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
edt2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

result = new ArrayList<String>();

btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        result.addAll(getTMSChart(edt1.getText().toString(), edt2.getText().toString()));

        Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ResultActivity.class);

        in.putExtra("gotonextpageX", result.get(0));
        in.putExtra("gotonextpageY", result.get(1));

        startActivity(in);
    }
});
}
private ArrayList<String> getTMSChart(String FromDate, String ToDate) 
{
// txt_1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

envelope.dotNet = true;

String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
String URL = "http://54.251.60.177/TMSOrdersService/TMSDetails.asmx";
String METHOD = "GetTMSChart";

SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD);
request.addProperty("FromDate", FromDate);
request.addProperty("ToDate", ToDate);

envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

String x = "", y = "";

ArrayList<String> stringResult = new ArrayList<String>();

try 
{
    androidHttpTransport.call(NAMESPACE + METHOD, envelope);
    SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
    SoapObject root = (SoapObject) ((SoapObject) (result).getProperty(0)).getProperty("NewDataSet");
    int tablesCount = root.getPropertyCount();

    for (int i = 0; i < tablesCount; i++) 
    {
        SoapObject table = (SoapObject) root.getProperty(i);
        int propertyCount = table.getPropertyCount();

        for (int j = 0; j < propertyCount; j++) 
        {

            stringResult.add(table.getPropertyAsString("Order_No").toString());
            stringResult.add(table.getPropertyAsString("Freight_Rate").toString());
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception e) 
{
}

return stringResult;
}}
```

thanks for your time!..

Comment: What is line 40 in ResultActivity?

Comment: Post the code please. it seems that by seeing your logs conversion of float to someother making this exception....Float ff = Float.parseFloat("String value");

Comment: @Ramkiran,@Rocky please find my sources from my question, i have updated my question with sources

Answer (score 0):

From the official docs:

"public class NumberFormatException
extends IllegalArgumentException

Thrown to indicate that the application has attempted to convert a string to one of the numeric types, but that the string does not have the appropriate format."

You might be trying to parse a string to a numeric type (in your case, a string to a double type) but the string might not have the proper format to be converted into a double type.

So in the code, when you are using the intent object to get the values, check if they are properly formatted. Or else, just format them properly when you insert them into the intent object that you use to call this activity i.e. intent.putExtra(...)

Answer (score 0):

```
double x_axis = Double.parseDouble(a); // Type casting
double y_axis = Double.parseDouble(b); // Type casting
```

Either a or b here can not be converted to a double. Maybe one of them is null, empty, or is not a number?

Comment: Where are you setting those extras? gotonextpageX and gotonextpageY

Comment: Actually i am setting it from the main activity..just a minute i'll update my question with main_WB.java

Comment: Please visit my question again..i have given main_WB.java for reference

Comment: Actually i am getting the x and y axis values from the web service by consuming it for creating a bar chart

Comment: As Heiko Rupp suggested, you should do some logging to make sure you are getting the values you expect. If they sometimes come back empty, you should check if they are empty (with TextUtils.isEmpty, which checks for null and an empty string) before trying to cast it to a double.

Comment: I'm sure,i am getting the right values from the web service but there is only problem on passing those values to the bar chart's x-axis and y-axis......

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to convert a string in

```
double x_axis = Double.parseDouble(a); // Type casting
double y_axis = Double.parseDouble(b); // Type casting
```

into a double. Now the parser tries to make sense of the inputstring and fails on characters that do not belong into a number e.g. the letter 'a'.

You may print the values of 'a' and 'b' before doing the parsing in order to see what they are  and to fix the parsing. Or start your app in a debugger and put a breakpoint on line 40.